# How to prepare colored images for neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, image-processing, conv-neural-network

I have seen many examples online regarding the MNIST dataset, but it's all in black and white. In that case, a 2D array can be constructed where the values at each array element represent the intensity of the corresponding pixel. However, what if I want to do colored images? What's the best way to represent the RGB data?

There's a very brief discussion of it [here](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap6.html#exercise_683491), which I quote below. However, I still don't get how the RGB data should be organized. Additionally, is there some OpenCV library/command we should use to preprocess the colored images?

> the feature detectors in the second convolutional-pooling layer have
>   access to all the features from the previous layer, but only within
>   their particular local receptive field*
>
> *This issue would have arisen in the first layer if the input images were in color. In that case we'd have 3 input features for each pixel,
>   corresponding to red, green and blue channels in the input image. So
>   we'd allow the feature detectors to have access to all color
>   information, but only within a given local receptive field.

Comment: Please do not [cross-post](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/9604/11097) :)

Comment: Sorry about that. What's the difference between the two? I will delete this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you represent each colour channel as a feature map.

So (if you follow pylearn conventions) your input will have shape (n_samples, 3, size_y, size_x).  Since images are usually stored colour-channel last (n_images, size_y, size_x, 3), in python you usually reformat your image collection with `feature_maps = np.rollaxis(image_collection, 3, 1)`

Comment: Awesome, I'll be sure the axes match next time!